# Can't access global variables from Python server

Tags: python

I am working on a small game server in Python using the class `SimpleWebSocketServer` found [here](https://github.com/opiate/SimpleWebSocketServer). Everything works great, but the problem is each time I want to access a variable, I have to use `self.variable_name`. Let me give an example.

```
class SimpleEcho(WebSocket):

    times_played_since_reset    = 0

    def handleMessage(self):
        global times_played_since_reset
        print times_played_since_reset
```

Whenever I try accessing `times_played_since_reset` using global it doesn't work and the server quits. Make it `self.times_played_since_reset` and everything works.

This variable needs affected by EVERY client connected. Unfortunately when I make it using self, only the client affects it's own instance. I need it to be where the client affects the class-wide variable instead of self.

Comment: That's not a global variable.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Wait... what is it then?

Comment: It's a class-level variable.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams How do I access it then?

Comment: On the class itself.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I'm sorry I'm a little confused here. Can you explain?

Comment: `SimpleEcho.times_played_since_reset`

Answer (score 0):

To access global variables from python server, use:

```
(Class Name).variable

SimpleEcho.times_played_since_reset
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using a mutable type for `times_played_since_reset` if you want it to be shared between all instances of the class.

Integers are not mutable, so they are not shared. As mentioned in the comments above, you could explicitly modify the class variable by doing something like `SimpleEcho.times_played_since_reset += 1` however this only works as long as the instance attribute of the same name has not explicitly been set/modified.

For instance, take this example class:

```
class Foo(object):
    bar = 1
```

If we create two instances:

```
>>> x = Foo()
>>> y = Foo()
```

Then:

```
>>> x.bar
1
>>> y.bar
1
```

And if we do:

```
>>> Foo.bar += 1
```

Then

```
>>> x.bar
2
>>> y.bar
2
```

**But** if we do:

```
>>> x.bar = 7
>>> Foo.bar +=1
```

Then:

```
>>> x.bar
7
>>> y.bar
3
```

If instead you were to use a mutable type like a list, For example like:

```
class Foo(object):
    bar = [1]
```

whether you modify `Foo.bar[0]` or `<instance>.bar.[0]` all current and future instances would see the change. This is because they all reference the same list, and you have modified the contents of the list rather than changing the specific object the variable points to.

However, if you were to assign a new list via `<instance>.bar = [78]`, only that instance would see the change and all other instances (current and future) would still reference the original list that was defined in the class definition.